# On Azure DevOps check if branch is only ahead by merge commits

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The **Behind | Ahead** on the ADO branches view is very useful to see at a glance, whether there are any features implemented in `develop` that yet need to be merged to `main`. When merging `develop` to `main`, we use merge-commits (no fast-forward) to allow GitVersion to automatically bump the minor SemVer-version of our tools. Thus `main` is always ahead of `develop` by an ever increasing number of merge-commits. Those merge-commits however never contain any file changes.

I'd like to also see at a glance, whether there are any file-changes that need to be merged back from `main` to `develop` (e.g. hotfixes).

How can I assure that developers remember to merge back hotfixes from `main` to `develop`?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to also see at a glance, whether there are any file-changes that need to be merged back from main to develop (e.g. hotfixes).

One way to accomplish this is with this single command:

`git diff origin/develop...origin/main --name-only`

Note there are **3 dots** there, which (specifically for `git diff`) means, "Show me the changes that are only on `main`."

If you get no output, then you have nothing *only* on `main`. If you get one or more files listed in the output, then you have some changes that need to be merged back into `develop`.

Note the `--name-only` flag just lists the files instead of the full diff of those files, but it's completely optional. I think I would prefer that for your use case to just get a "yes or no" answer.

**Side note about dots**: The dot notation is kind of confusing in Git. With `git diff`, if you use 2 dots instead of 3 dots, you would get the full diff of the two branches. This is sort of the opposite of what 2 and 3 dots means with `git log`. In `git log`, two dots is "show me only new commits on the right side", whereas three dots is "show me new commits on either side".

Comment: I adjusted my initial answer to reflect your way simpler method.

Answer (score 0):

I created a ticket on the [Visual Studio developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Mark-if-branch-is-only-ahead-by-commits/1419982) for this.

As a workaround, I currently use a nightly pipeline to check, whether `main` is ahead of `develop` only by merge-commits. This way, developers remember to merge hotfixes back to `develop`.

```yaml
schedules:
- cron: "45 1 * * Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri"
  branches:
    include:
    - main

steps:
- powershell: |
    if (git diff origin/develop...origin/main --name-only) {
        throw "There are file changes on the main branch that are NOT on the develop branch. Please create a pull request from main to develop."
    }

    Write-Host "All file changes from the main branch are merged into the develop branch." -ForegroundColor Green
  displayName: "Check develop ahead of main"
```